# Registering a WcfClient in the container when the URI not yet known

Tags: castle-windsor, wcf-client

At the time I am registering a new WCF endpoint I do not know what the URI is...

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
   var defaultClientModel = new DefaultClientModel
   {
     Endpoint = WcfEndpoint
       .ForContract<IMyService>()
       .BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None))
       .At(  URI??? )
   };

   container.Register(WcfClient.ForChannels(defaultClientModel));
}
```

Is there some way I can retrieve the URI from the container at the time the IMyService instance is requested (this is when it is known)?

Is there a factory method/dynamic parameter sort of thing that could be used?

Comment: Why don't you know what the URI is? Where are you getting your URI from?

Comment: The service that knows the URI is in the container. I don't want to reference the container in a service-locator fashion. Janco's is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're able to do so using the following syntax in Windsor 3.1:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyService>()
    .AsWcfClient()
    .DependsOn((k, d) =>
        d["EndPoint"] = WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None)).At( URI??? )));
}
```

Windsor will attempt to resolve the endpoint using the given dynamic resolution delegate at the point when an IMyService is first resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the [UsingFactoryMethod](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Using_a_delegate_as_component_factory_6) to create your services.

- I would register a custom UriResolver with the container
- Resolve an instance of the said UriResolver in the factory method (which doesn't get called until the service needs to be resolved)
- Create the service in the factory method
- Search through the Castle Windsor doco and swear a lot.

The following links may be of use

[ravendb, castle IoC ,Wcf facility - doc session liefstyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310397/ravendb-castle-ioc-wcf-facility-doc-session-liefstyle)

[Using Castle Windsor WcfFacility to create client endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085172/using-castle-windsor-wcffacility-to-create-client-endpoints)

http://www.mail-archive.com/castle-project-users@googlegroups.com/msg09012.html (this one looks to have similar code to what you need)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250077/problems-using-castle-windsor-factory-method

[Passing parameters to UsingFactoryMethod in Castle Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453648/passing-parameters-to-usingfactorymethod-in-castle-windsor)

[Castle Windsor: UsingFactoryMethod can't instantiate with a weird error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837893/castle-windsor-usingfactorymethod-cant-instantiate-with-a-weird-error)

http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1